# Contents of a programs memory (Mac)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, memory

Is there a utility that will show me a program's current memory contents? Like a hex dump of the entire memory being used by the program? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

My utility, [Bit Slicer](http://zgcoder.net/#bit-slicer), which runs on 10.6 or later can do this for regular applications.

1) Run the program and select a target process.

2) Go to Tools -> Dump All Memory... This will save all the current readable memory in a directory with a bunch of files each indicating a particular memory region and a file that merges everything as well. These files can then be viewed with a hex editor.

3) There's also the real-time memory viewer in the Memory menu for looking at a particular spot.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on 11.6

Comment: It should still work from the Memory menu, but memory may not be readable if the process has hardened runtime / library validation enabled + SIP is enabled, these days.

Answer (score 1):

Dmalloc - Debug Malloc Library

This program came with OS 10.6 but it seems to have disappeared with OS 10.7 (which has many, many, many ... programming complications).  Excluding 10.7 regrets, Dmalloc is wonderful way to examine every memory allocation.

Ah ha...

Mac OS 10.7 provides Menu-Product-Profile.  I have not investigated fully used it, however, I recognize the Dmalloc icon within it.